# HTML button inside a Razor component within a Razor page

Tags: html, asp.net-core, button, razor

I have a page called CreateForm
On my CreateForm page, after the customer enters the data, they can preview their entry before I save it to the database. Their Preview is a Razor component and contains an html button to submit.

The problem I have is if a customer is click happy, he may click the button multiple times creating multiple copies. Therefore I want to disable the button after the first click. How can I grab the button's handle?

From the CreateForm razor page, I have this embeded Razor component

```
    <CustomerPreviewRequest HeadingToShow="@HeadingToShowPreviewCustomerScreen"
                            onBack="MoveToPreviousPage"
                            CurrentCustomerSubmission="@_model">

    </CustomerPreviewRequest>
```

inside the CustomerPreviewRequest, here's how I define the button

```
            <button aria-label="Submit Request." type="submit" class="login100-form-btn" style="background-color:#1a2b57"
                    tabindex="0" id="submitForm">
                Submit Request
            </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you only want the customer to submit the data once and then disable the submit button? You can take a look at this simple demo:

View:

```
<p style="text-align:center"> 
    <form id="yourFormId" name="yourFormId" method="post" action="#">

        <input type="text" /><br />
        <input type="submit" class="submitBtn" value="Submit Requestt" />
    </form>
</p>




<!--script to disable the submit button -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submitBtn").click(function () {
        $(".submitBtn").attr("disabled", true);
        return true;
    });
});

</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to do this with C#/Blazor and not resort to jQuery/JavaScript.